# Eclipse delete word behavior

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-pdt

What preference in Eclipse controls how much is deleted when you press control-delete/backspace?  This is the delete whole word command as defined by the operating system (but I imagine expanded on in Eclipse).

In CDT, it's great.  If you press control-delete in some white space it will delete all the way up to the first character.  Like so (with `|` being the cursor):

```
function |      foo() {
```

gives you:

```
function foo() {
```

But in PDT, it's terrible!  It behaves as if white space isn't a word and deletes the white space and the next word:

```
function () {
```

How can I make PDT behave like CDT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been a couple of PDT editor bugs (like [bug 210108](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=210108) or [bug 247630](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=247630)).

So if this ("this" being the improper <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> behavior) is confirmed with the [latest PDT version](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) (like 2.2.0), this is a god candidate for a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=pdt).