# Eclipse : change behavior of "Delete Next Word" on Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse

I am running Eclipse Kepler on Linux, on a Debian, with JDK 7u60,

```bash
$ uname -a
Linux debian-1234 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.57-3+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And at home, I am not using Linux, but Windows 7, with the same Eclipse Kepler.

I have this XML element (from a pom.xml), the `|` represent my cursor.

```xml
  |  <packaging>war</packaging>
```

Pressing Ctrl + Delete will do:

- on Windows : the behavior is what I want, it will remove the whitespace before `<packaging>`, like :

  ```xml
    |<packaging>war</packaging>
  ```
- on Linux : the behavior is **not** what I want. It will remove the whitespace **and** `<packaging`. The result is `>war</packaging>`.

  ```xml
    |>war</packaging>
  ```

But if I do the same in a Java Editor, it works :

```java
|  final String myString = "foobar";
```

Transforms into :

```java
|final String myString = "foobar";
```

I have found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011725/eclipse-delete-word-behavior), which describe my problem, but I don't want t a solution that works only for some plugins. I want a solution which works for the GTK component which behave (for me) bad.

I can also produce this behavior in  Firefox textarea's.